# Disable selection effect when selecting UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I disable the selection effect when selecting a particular `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 24):

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

use this

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

Comment: for swift 3.0 use cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

Comment: Swift 4.2 its  `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none`

Comment: Swift 5.3 `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
  }
```

The job is done by setting:

`cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 4.5/5.0**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

Or,

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 2):

There a delegate method to setselectionstyle to none.Once this is set reloading the table gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

or

`[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath dataSource method`

Answer (score 0):

Write this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index` method,

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

OR

`[self.tblName deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this one:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
```

Consider this behavior for other tableviews in your app.